# for dinámico o bucle

Tags: javascript, bucle-for, function, console

Sería de mucha ayuda si me dijeran que estoy haciendo mal. Necesito hacer un for dinámico con la siguiente indicaciones:

Definí ahora la función sumaDeLosParesDel0Al(x) que tome como parámetro un número X y que devuelva el total de la suma de todos los números que son pares del 0 al X (incluyendo a X).
Suponiendo que X es par ésta función hará la siguiente operación: 0 + 2 + 4 + 6 + 8 + 10 + ... x

Mi código es el siguiente:

```js
function sumaDeLosParesDel0A1(x) {
  let suma = 0
  for (i = 0; i <= x; i++) {
    if ((i % 2) == 0) {
      suma = suma + i
    }
  }
  return suma
}

console.log(sumaDeLosParesDel0A1(4))
```

Me sale los siguientes errores:
La función sumaDeLosParesDel0Al tiene que estar definida
La función sumaDeLosParesDel0Al debe recibir un parámetro
La función sumaDeLosParesDel0Al(6) debe retornar 12
La función sumaDeLosParesDel0Al(10) debe retornar 30

Comment: Tu código parece estar correcto, lo probé con 6 y 10 y da respectivamente 12 y 30. ¿No será que estas escribiendo la función como `sumaDeLosParesDel0A1` (con un 1 al final) y en realidad es: `sumaDeLosParesDel0Al` (con una L minúscula al final)?

Comment: Por cierto, bienvenida a SO, gana tu primera medalla dándote una vuelta por el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: @FranAcuna muchas gracias, en efecto el error era la letra del final!!! muchas muchas gracias!

Comment: Igualmente, si me permites la optimización, no hace falta que uses la variable `suma`.  Con hacer dentro del bucle un console.log(i) bastaría: